# How to write a command for hotkey that launch or restore minimized window

Tags: linux, debian, kde

How to write a command that would launch an application or if it was already running, would restore the minimized window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following bash script launch app or activate its window if app is already running:

```
#!/bin/bash
C=`xdotool search --class $1 | tail -1`
if [ -z "$C" ]
then
    `$1 &`
else
    xdotool windowactivate --sync $C
fi
```

And then use it on hotkey:

```
./launch.sh <some_app>
```

for example:

```
/path_to_script/launch.sh keepassx
```

Comment: Welcome to U/L, and thanks for coming back and posting the solution!

Comment: AFAIK this doesn't restore a minimized window